# How do I calculate the row offset in a sparse matrix representation?

Tags: c, storage, sparse-matrix

I'm writing a SpMxV (sparse matrix vector multiplication) program where I store the sparse matrix in a [CRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR_or_CRS.29) format and then carry out the operations. [Here's a short introduction](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~dongarra/etemplates/node373.html) on the format.

I know how to acquire the val and col_index_array arrays:

```
for (row_idx = 0; row_idx < row_count; row_idx++) {
        for (col_idx = 0; col_idx < column_count; col_idx++) {
            if (sparse_matrix[row_idx][col_idx] != 0) {
                val[i] = sparse_matrix[row_idx][col_idx];
                col_idx_array[i] = col_idx;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

But I got stuck at acquiring the `row_ptr` indexes. How do I actually calculate them?

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: There are several conventions for `row_offsets`/`row_ptr`. Some simply hold the invariant that `row_offsets[i + 1] - row_offsets[i]` is the number of entries in row number i (starting at zero). Some conventions always assume `row_offsets[0] = 0` and therefore leave this entry, since it's always zero and shift the rest of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

```
row_ptr[i + 1] - row_ptr[i] = number of values in row i
```

therefore we simply have to store the current number of entries `i` in `row_ptr` when we look at the next row:

```
for (row_idx = 0; row_idx < row_count; row_idx++) {
    row_ptr[row_idx] = i;
    /* other code ommited */
}
row_ptr[row_idx] = i; /* equivalent to row_ptr[row_count] = i;
                       * total number of entries
                       */
```

Note that this assumes that your arrays are 0-indexed, whereas the introduction you've posted assumes 1-indexed arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Taking your code would look something like this:

**for** (row_idx = 0; row_idx < row_count; row_idx++) {
  **for** (col_idx = 0; col_idx < column_count; col_idx++) {
    **if** (sparse_matrix[row_idx][col_idx] != 0) {
      val[i] = sparse_matrix[row_idx][col_idx];
      col_idx_array[i] = col_idx;
      i++;
    }
  }
  row_ptr[row_idx+1]=i;
}